# Simple SQL questions, counting and ordering

Tags: sql

Given an SQL database called Purchases with columns items and name, will the following query count the number of items ending in 'red' and show the result for each name record in descending order?

```
SELECT COUNT(item) as "Number of red", Name 
FROM Purchases 
WHERE item LIKE '%red' 
ORDER BY "Number of red items" DESC
```

Comment: Well, run it. What does it do?

Comment: PS: No, it will fail. And if the error that makes it fail, is fixed, it still won't do what you ask.

Comment: It runs for me without an error - though it doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Presumably because you're using MySQL - I think this would fail in most other SQLs.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the query you are looking for.

```
SELECT COUNT(item) as "Number of red", Name
FROM Purchases
WHERE item LIKE '%red'
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY COUNT(item) DESC
```